# Drupal taxonomy break after using mytheme_preprocess_node function

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to make custom drupal 7 template. I want print breadcrumb on the top of every node page. I'm using Breadcrumb and menu Breadcrumb module. I had trouble put my breadcrumb on page so I decided to create new region, then put breadcrumb block inside it, and render it on my page. Because regions are not available by default in node template, I used function like that:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

  // Get a list of all the regions for this theme
  foreach (system_region_list($GLOBALS['theme']) as $region_key => $region_name) {

    // Get the content for each region and add it to the $region variable
    if ($blocks = block_get_blocks_by_region($region_key)) {
      $variables['region'][$region_key] = $blocks;
    }
    else {
      $variables['region'][$region_key] = array();
    }
  }
}
```

It's work nice, but after add that taxonomy module just behave weird. It stopped working on other pages than main page. Any idea what may cause that?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the weird behavior? You might try removing the foreach and just using `if ($blocks = block_get_blocks_by_region('breadcrumb')) {
      $variables['region']['breadcrumb'] = $blocks;
    }` and replace 'breadcrumb' with the machine name of the breadcrumb region you created. There's no need to run through each region when you know which one you need.